# Looping through a table in MS-Access when a counter hits 0 in the table

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, events, dao

I was going to have the table copy a record when it hits 0 and paste the data from that table to another table then delete it, but no one would post on my question. So, I am using a form as a POS for production. Basically they scan the product and it is assigned to a work order that has a countdown called ToGo and then takes the data and places it in an inventory for shipping. When the product is scanned everything works, but I need the code to loop through the work orders when the ToGo hits 0. So here is my code

```
Private Sub ItemCode_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set Db = CurrentDb

Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("Select ToGo from WorkOrders where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)

With rs
    .Edit
    !ToGo = !ToGo - 1
    .Update
    .Edit
   

End With
End Sub
```

In the table of WorkOrders the fields are Work Order Number, Creation Date, Supervisor, SKU, Barcode, Product Name, To Build, To Go, and Built. The work order number is a simple one like 'W25', the SKU is a simple text that is over the barcode, The To Build is a Reference number, the To Go is the same number as the To Build when first entered, but decreases when scanned, and Bult is a reference fr shipping.

I have built a form to show everything from The InventoryManagment table which is all the products with SKU, barcode, and quantity on hand. When scanned on the form the quantity goes up 1 and updates on the InventoryManagment table. The Work Order Number and the To Go is also displayed on the form to show what production needs to make.

Now, on the floor. The production workers have a station that they are assigned to each day. They can be assigned to a different work station daily. The have multiple parts and hardware that they use to build a product. Then place in a package with a barcode scan. That barcode scan is actually used in stores when you buy our product. They are using clickers to keep track of how many they make per work order and then placing it in a box. I am making the form so they can just scan instead of using the clicker. I have the work orders to show on the form also.

I want it to loop through the work order so that when a product To Go hits 0 then the next work order starts with that same barcode. It's a tracking system to make the right amount of products per work order. I sooner or later want that work order to delete off that table but be placed in a done work order table for shipping.

Comment: _I want it to change from work order 25 to another work order_ ... eh, which work order and why?

Comment: Different stations do different products. So one station could be building a product but the next product for that work order is not being built at there station. So, the work order needs to loop for the specific products at their workstations.

Comment: That sounds more like a business rule rather than a coding issue. Set up a list of products for each workstation and filter on these.

Comment: So, can I not loop by the barcode?

Comment: If you mean search for it until found somewhere and, if not found, do something else, then: Yes. But we don't have the details to suggest how.

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: You mention _ToGo hits 0_. What should happen or not at that point, and/or what your coding issue might be, I don't understand. Have in mind please, that we have no idea what is going on in your production hall.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Why do you follow Update line with another Edit?

Comment: Not sure why that is there. It works without it also.

Comment: This site is so awesome on giving answers. Every post I have posted someone replies then I give them the answer to their question then they just not answer back. Maybe answer back with what else you need or it's not possible.